# Finding a list of keys containing equal values in a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I want to find a list (of lists) of all keys in a dictionary that contain values equal to other elements.

For example:

```
dict_with_dups = {
    "a": 1,
    "b": 1,
    "c": 1,
    "d": 2,
    "e": 3,
    "f": 3,
    "g": 4,
}

keys_with_same = locate_same_keys(dict_with_dups)

for key_list in keys_with_same:
    print(f"{key_list}")
```

The above should print this:

```
['a', 'b', 'c']
['e', 'f']
```

How do I most efficiently write the function `locate_same_keys`?

Comment: If you show an attempt at solving it, you'll be more likely to get help!

Comment: What was the problem when you tried to write that function (efficient or not)?

Comment: Try reading some of the various questions about [reversing a dict](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5D+reverse+a+dict)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the duplicate values from the dictionary using a **flipped dictionary**.

You can create it by iterating over the original dictionary and adding each value to the flipped dictionary as a key, and it's key as it's value. Then, if the value appears again in the original dictionary, add it's key as another value in the flipped dictionary.

Then you can just go over each key in the flipped dictionary, check if it has more than 1 value and if so, print it:

```
dict_with_dups = {
    "a": 1,
    "b": 1,
    "c": 1,
    "d": 2,
    "e": 3,
    "f": 3,
    "g": 4,
}

# finding duplicate values from dictionary using flip 
flipped = {} 

# iterate over the original dictionary and check if each value is associated 
# with more than one key
for key, value in dict_with_dups.items(): 
    if value not in flipped: 
        flipped[value] = [key] 
    else: 
        flipped[value].append(key) 

# printing all values that are assosiated with more then one key
for key, value in flipped.items():
    if len(value)>1:
        print(value)
```

**Output**:

```
['a', 'b', 'c']
['e', 'f']
```

Regarding **efficiency**, creating the flipped dictionary requires going over all the key, value pairs in the original dictionary, so we get `O(n)` time complexity.

Comment: More pythonic is to use defaultdict than using such `if ... else` construction.

Comment: @GrzegorzBokota I agree. However, I thought that a flipped dictionary solution is easier to understand.

Answer (score 1):

Iterate over dict items and for each value add key to proper list.

```
from collections import defaultdict

res = defaultdict(list)

for k, v in dict_with_dups.items():
    res[v].append(k)

for v in res.values():
    if len(v) > 1:
        print(v)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
dict_with_dups = {
    "a": 1,
    "b": 1,
    "c": 1,
    "d": 2,
    "e": 3,
    "f": 3,
    "g": 4,
}
result = {}
for val in dict_with_dups:
    if dict_with_dups[val] in result:
        result[dict_with_dups[val]].append(val)
    else:
        result[dict_with_dups[val]] = [val]    

for key, value in result.items():
   if len(value)>1:
      print(value)
```

it will give u all list with the same keys like this

[image]

Comment: Your output Is not what was asked for.

Answer (score 0):

```
dict_with_dups = {
    "a": 1,
    "b": 1,
    "c": 1,
    "d": 2,
    "e": 3,
    "f": 3,
    "g": 4,
}

result = list(filter(lambda z: len(z)>1,
                     (list(map(lambda y: y[0],
                               filter(lambda x: x[1]==v, dict_with_dups.items())))
                      for v in set(dict_with_dups.values()))))
```

or

```
result = [z for z in ([x[0] for x in dict_with_dups.items() if x[1]==v]
                      for v in set(dict_with_dups.values()))
          if len(z)>1]
```

as suggested by @wjandrea.

For me, the first variant is more clear (but less concise).

Comment: `list(filter(lambda`? Use a list comprehension instead - it's much more readable: `[z for z in ... if len(z)>1]`. And for the `list(map(lambda`, use a generator expression instead: `(y[0] for y in ...)`.

Comment: On second thought I think it would be clearer to do it in two steps: map, filter. (Not nitpicking, just thinking out loud.)